# Android WebView UTF-8 not showing

Tags: android, unicode, webview

I have a webview and am trying to load simple UTF-8 text into it.

```
mWebView.loadData("將賦予他們的傳教工作標示為", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

But the WebView displays ANSI/ASCII garbage.

Obviously an encoding issue, but what am I missing in telling the webview to display the Unicode text?

This is a HelloWorld app.

Comment: Solution: Use the other other method on WebView --> mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "將賦予他們的傳教工作標示為", "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank");

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use:

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "將賦予他們的傳教工作標示為", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

or using WebSettings with [setDefaultTextEncoding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultTextEncodingName%28java.lang.String%29):

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

#### For recent versions of Android, API 16 to 22 it was tested and work properly using loadData() method, requires the mimeType to include: "charset=utf-8".

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");                   
mWebView.loadData(myCharacters, "text/html; charset=utf-8",null);
```

or

```
  mWebView.loadData(myCharacters, "text/html; charset=utf-8","UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why this works, is it a bug? For me I can display UTF correctly using `loadData` pre-Honeycomb but it doesn't work on Honeycomb. I've made the change as above for Honeycomb and it is now displaying correctly.

Comment: Hi PJL it was reported as an issue "Issue 3552 - android - WebView.loadData() doesn't show Japanese ..." code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3552, but now its just a broken link =0

Comment: Not only Japanese, it seems that this problem appears with Arabic characters too.

Comment: loadDataWithBaseURL() is working for me. WebSettings does not.

Comment: loadDataWithBaseURL() is working for me too :) great ans.thanks :)

Comment: hey can u plz specify what is the 2nd parameter on loadDatawithBaseURL

Comment: the second parameter, data is a string to load into the webview. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Any chance you could explain why the first method is working? instead of loadData?

Comment: loadDataWithBaseURL() worked for me too. WebSettings does not make any difference.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for android 4.4. any more :-(. This duplicate question [android-webview-with-garbled-utf-8-characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933069/android-webview-with-garbled-utf-8-characters) has a working solution for more modern androids

Comment: Thanks for it! mWebView.loadData(topHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8",null); work for me for arabic.

Comment: Thank you! it works for me, italian accented characters

Comment: @MathijsSegers If you check my answer you'll see this is an issue with Android itself. Furthermore, it will exhibit different behavior on different manufacturers version of Android.

Answer (score 10):

### This problem goes back to at least Gingerbread

This seems to have been broken in some form or fashion forever.
[Issue 1733](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1733#c23)

### Use loadDataWithBaseURL instead of loadData

```
// Pretend this is an html document with those three characters
String scandinavianCharacters = "øæå";

// Won't render correctly
webView.loadData(scandinavianCharacters, "text/html", "UTF-8");

// Will render correctly
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, scandinavianCharacters, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Now the part that is truly annoying is that on the Samsung Galaxy S II (4.0.3) loadData() works just fine, but testing on the Galaxy Nexus (4.0.2) the multi-byte characters are garbled unless you use loadDataWithBaseURL(). [WebView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

### Recent versions of Android

Some are reporting a change in the behavior of the loadData calls requiring the `mimeType` to include `charset=utf-8`.

```
webView.loadData(scandinavianCharacters, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

#### Discussion

The first time I saw this my boss brought me his phone, an early Nexus, while I was developing at the time on a Samsung Galaxy II and it showed up in our economic news feed on his phone which had a lot of non-ASCII characters. So, not only is this a long standing issue within Android, but it also isn't consistent between device makers. This is a matter where you have to program defensively.

Answer (score 0):

So much time has elapsed and still an issue!

None of these answers worked for me. Maybe I had a slightly different situation. The text string I was loading was coming from a file in res/raw and it is being displayed in an AlertDialog. I had three unicode symbols in the file. I tried all of the methods above and everyone one worked and produced identical results on the Android screen, **but the unicode symbols were displayed as their raw form**, for example \u1F4F6. They were not rendered.

I was using an Android Nexus 5 OS 6.

Finally I did this (changing the \u to 0x)

```
    WebView help = helpContent.findViewById(R.id.helpView);
    help.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
    helpText = helpText.replace("0x1F4F6", new String(Character.toChars(0x1F4F6)));
    helpText = helpText.replace("0x1F4DE", new String(Character.toChars(0x1F4DE)));
    helpText = helpText.replace("0x2796", new String(Character.toChars(0x2796)));
    help.loadData(helpText, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

and it worked. This is not a solution but a pathetic hack and would never work in general.
If anyone knows why I need to do this I would be grateful!

Note I also tried different manners of representing the unicode symbols as, for example, in w3schools and none worked.