# Show special characters in a webview

Tags: android, unicode, webview

I have a text (sInfoText) with a lots of special characters like 'è'.

I would like to show this special character also in a webview, but I get rubbish characters. Howto convert this special characters programmatically?

```
wvinfo.loadData(sInfoText,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: try wvinfo.loadData(sInfoText, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);.ll work on above 4.0.0

Comment: `I have a text`... Make sure that this text is originally saved in UTF-8. It won't be converted to UTF-8.

Comment: @Dhwanik : Thanks a lot , that solved it. If you like you can answer and I will accept.

Comment: @user1344545 answer added,..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView with garbled UTF-8 characters.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933069/android-webview-with-garbled-utf-8-characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
wvinfo.loadData(sInfoText, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

this ll work on above 4.0.0