# Special Symbols not showing in webview

Tags: android, character-encoding, android-webview

Symbols not getting in android WebView

For More Info please see the drive link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=17PXFPJnVYkuGA_fkQPxskeIaw8AlzkcD

```
binding.tvQuestion.loadDataWithBaseURL("", questionlist.title, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
binding.tvQuestion.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

How can I show the special characters/unicode characters?

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27999043/5110595)

Answer (score 1):

Try

Setting the correct encoding in html file as a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Android Load Data

```
webView.loadData("", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Android Setting

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");  
webView.loadData("", "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);
```

Replace Special Character if you not usable

```
mwebView.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(data, "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+"," "), "text/html", "utf-8");
```