# Why I am getting some unwanted characters in my webview?

Tags: android, utf-8, android-webview

I saw a lot of post and suggestions saying to use "utf-8", and I am using it but getting some extra characters in the web view.[image: The extra characters can be seen in the image]

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://" + file1, htmltext, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

I also tried

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();             
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10831462/3395198

Comment: My code is similar to the  answer code given there  // Will render correctly
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, scandinavianCharacters, "text/html", "UTF-8", null); but it is not working  @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: have you tried this
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "file:///android_asset/home.html", "text/html", "utf-8",null);

Comment: getting a compilation error @RameshR  for first and last null and also I tried it just with the html string but getting the same result.              mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmltext, "text/HTML", "utf-8",null);