# Unicode support in webview on android 4.2

Tags: android, unicode, utf-8, webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My android application was displaying unicode chars properly till android 4.1 .  But now on Android 4.2 jelly bean, unicode chars are not getting displayed.
I used the following settings as suggested by various forums :

```
web.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Also my htmlData variable has the meta content-type setting as urf-8

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
```

I don't know where I am making a mistake. Its working fine on all versions prior to 4.2
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods that you are using are right,

[Android WebView UTF-8 not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312643/android-webview-utf-8-not-showing/3313266#3313266)

but probably you are facing a bug.

[Wrong character set displayed for Telugu unicode on Nexus 7 - Jelly Bean 4.2.1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41891)

> I can confirm that this issue is resolved now with the latest update
>   to 4.2.2

Update:

If you believe a new bug is found.
**Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker**
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Hey heres your issue reported!:)

[Gurmukhi (Punjabi) Unicode support in webview on android 4.2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65969&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried with 4.2.2 also and the Punjabi Unicode support is still broken..Please guide where to report the BUG.