# webview justify not show Persia(Farsi)/RTL Language Correctly

Tags: android, webview, text-justify, right-justified

i need to make justify for webview to show Persian(Farsi)/RTL String.

i use below code :

```
    String text = "<html><body>"
                      + "<p align=\"justify\">"                
                      + getString(R.string.test1) 
                      + "</p> "
                      + "</body></html>";
            webView.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

but webview can't show persian character - below image :

[image]

what i to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView UTF-8 not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312643/android-webview-utf-8-not-showing)

Comment: @Dev-iL , so tanx it was helpful - just , how i can use "\n" in text for showing in webview - i use "\n" but show "\n" no new line!

Comment: I believe that in html a line break is done by '<br>'

Comment: @Dev-iL , right , but i read data from "getString(R.string.test1)",in this solution i must write String and i can not read data from string.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok , Finally i found a good way to make justify + using "\n" + all other customize for String.

1. i make a HTML file contain customized string
2. Load data to WebView to thisway :

   ```
   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/string.htm");
   ```

### Edit :

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, yourString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Answer (score 2):

To load data use

```
webView.loadData(text, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "utf-8");
```

By default this does not support RTL. To fix it I use HTML tag:

```
String headerText = "<html><body dir=\"rtl\"; style=\"text-align:justify;background-color:#fff3eb;\">";
```

And to end of String add:

```
String footerText = "</body></html>";
```