# Language other than English displaying garbage character in webview in android

Tags: java, android, api, webview

I tried all the method answered for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312643/android-webview-utf-8-not-showing) question. Neither of these are working for me.

FYI: The api url format for the webview is like  : `https://host/folder/file.exe`

It is working fine for device api less than 5.0 but not on high end device (api>5.0)

I would be greatly obliged for this answer.