# How can I solve this font error in Android?

Tags: android

I want to display a HTML string on Webview in Android, but that string is Vietnamese string. Therefore, It can't display a Vietnamese string as I expect and displays a strange string. Help me, please.

My Vietnamese string is "Vị trí của tính từ trong câu"
and it displays "Vá>>>$a tÃnh tá>><< trong cÃcu"

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312643/android-webview-utf-8-not-showing

Comment: What is HTML string?!! See what encoding your browser uses to encode the string. In firefox look at View->Text Encoding menu.